# add +1 to random range stopping point

Tags: python, random

hey I started programming and I have this problem maybe u can help me
the following code creates a random number range from ut starting value up to ur stopping value -1

is there a line of ode that i can add so that it takes my stopping value and adds one to it with no errors ?

I have already tried with `range_stop = int(range_stop) +1` 
but it didn't work out.

thank you, have a nice day

```
range_stop = input("type a number for ur stoppping point of the range: ")

if range_start.isdigit():
    range_start = int(range_start)
    if range_start < 0:
        print("please make sure to type no negative numbers")
        

if range_stop.isdigit():
    range_stop = int(range_stop)
    if range_stop <= 0 and range_stop <= range_start:
        print("please make sure to write a stop value that is greater than 0 and the start value")

r = random.randrange(range_start, range_stop)
```

Comment: *stopping value -1* shouldn't you **subtract** 1?

Comment: @Guy, no I think the point is that they want to counteract the -1

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: what does `range_stop = int(range_stop) +1`  but it didn't work out mean?

Comment: I still don't understand what is your problem - why it doesn't work? Use `print()` to see what you have in variable and you should see value increased by 1

Answer (score 0):

```
range_stop = input("type a number for ur stoppping point of the range: ")
>>> 3 # set range_stop to 3
>>> print(int(range_stop) + 1)
>>> 4 # return 3 + 1
```

`int(range_stop) + 1` works perfectly for me

Comment: oh nvm i dont know what i did before and why it didnt work but now it does thank you sir :)